# How to replace Android Toolbar icons programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ListView` and a `Toolbar` above of it in my `Activity`. I want to replace the `Toolbar` default icons (search and settings) with delete and edit icons when clicking an item of the `ListView` to perform some action.

Comment: You can define the menu XML icon however you want

Comment: @cricket_007, i do not want to replace the icons completely. I mean replacing them temporarilly for editing a clicked element and then the Toolbar takes back its icons.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a contextual action bar. http://www.technotalkative.com/contextual-action-bar-cab-android/

Comment: Yes, exactly!!!. Thank you bro!!. I did not know about it before.

Comment: Please include your code and xml/menu that relate to the problem. It is better if you can provide screen shot too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I've understood from your question, you're looking for [ActionMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html) which might serve your purpose.

So here's an implementation guideline.

Declare an `ActionMode` in your `Activity` and let your `Activity` to implement `ActionMode.Callback`.

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionMode.Callback {

    // Declare ActionMode here
    private ActionMode actionMode;

    // Now implement the callback functions for ActionMode 
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(final ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = actionMode.getMenuInflater();

        // Inflate your menu here 
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_item_click_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_delete:
                // Do something
                actionMode.finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_edit:
                // Do something
                actionMode.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
        try {
            this.actionMode = null;
            // Do something. Reset the views maybe? 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now to initiate your `ActionMode` you need to have this in your `onClick` function of the list item.

```
listItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (actionMode != null) {
            return true;
        }

        // Show ActionMode 
        actionMode = startSupportActionMode(this);
        actionMode.invalidate();
    }
});
```

You may need to reset the `ActionMode` sometimes.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (actionMode != null) {
        actionMode.finish();
        actionMode = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Raez Murshard, this is exactly what i needed as @cricket_007 suggested..